# Need confirmation: Membership scheduled reminders do not sent to any email on bounce lists?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders, bounce

We ran our membership renewal reminder for the first time on our live data and found as expected that contacts whose email address is in the 'on-hold' category are skipped when sending out membership reminders.

But we also have additional skipped contacts, and we found some of them were on bounce lists but haven't triggered the 'on-hold' threshold yet.

Can someone please verify/falsify that even contacts  on 'temporary bounce', are skipped when sending out membership renewal reminders?

Or alternatively point me to the tables/module handling this part of the feature.

I will report back to this thread.

Comment: how are you sending out Membership Reminders? Using CiviMail or a Scheduled Reminder.

Comment: Scheduled reminders.

Comment: ok - but this was tagged as CiviMail - can you change it and help make it really clear - eg in title too - that this is Scheduled Reminders

Comment: I really appreciate your cosmetic suggestions to increase accuracy and archiving. It's however lost luve and highly superficial, if no one actually answers the question, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Mail is designed to go out so long as email is not on hold. The point of the bounce thresholds is ensure the system keeps sending to an email address in cases where there is a reasonable prospect that the email will get through. And to not send when the likelihood drops too low.

Suggestions if small propotion of list not seeing email:
1. Have client check spam folder.
2. Set up SPF record for the emailing domain.
3. Reduce 'spamminess' of mailings, eg no attachments, no broken html, no words likely to be flagged. 
4. Use a mail delivery service like the Mandrill one we put out when they provided 12k free emails per month (I think minimum spend is now $35-40/month so targetted at bigger installations), or the new SparkPost integration extension.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the general principles. We see that scheduled reminder don't go out for a few people: Their emails are not on hold, but they have been seen on bounce lists. It would be helpful to know if the hypothesis is correct, that scheduled reminder module uses the bounce list and eliminates receipients from the list or if they only go towards the "Hold" list. In the former case, my work tracking down why some people don't get included in the scheduled reminders is done, the latter means, there are other reasons why they didn't get a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I am spitballing a little bit here, but could one possibility be that they are on hold in your mailing service, even if not in CiviCRM? For example, if you send mail through SparkPost and the contact is not on hold in CiviCRM but is blocked in SparkPost due to previous bounces, the mail may go through CiviCRM to SparkPost, but not from SparkPost to the contact.

Comment: Quite possible, in theory. Both - scheduled reminders and CiviMail - go through the same SMTP server, so CiviCRM is the only instance holding all the information.